# If errors occur in my initialization code, how do I record that in my log?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, initialization, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this code in my config/initializers/websocket_client.rb file

```
module WebsocketClient
  class Proxy
    WS = WebSocket::Client::Simple.connect 'ws://localhost:8000/proxy'
  end
end

WebsocketClient::Proxy::WS.on :message do |msg|
    # Store this in teh Rails cache so that other workers know what
    # the current job is
    json_data = JSON.parse( msg.data )
    if json_data['type'] == "job"
      worker_id = "4AN8nk7YjFNB19M41bP3rJXwRL9CGzkKmZuAQssdnk8j92qxgvV76XNFXMpypJ92LJXDYjxdSbE5UadhNvdHwM1CDBy4pDD"
      cache_key = StratumWorker.get_cache_key(worker_id)
      Rails.cache.delete(cache_key)
      Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key) do
        []
      end
      Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key).push( json_data )
    end
    ActionCable.server.broadcast 'work', data: msg.data
end
```

I'm using Rails 5.1.  What I notice is taht if an exception occurs somewhere in this block, the exception is not recorded on my console or my log/development.log file.  What do I need to configure in order that exceptions taht occur above can be recorded in my log?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create simple model for this job. For example `app/models/add_log.rb`:

```
class AddLog
  def self.exceptions(message=nil)
    @add_log ||= Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/exceptions.log")
    @add_log.exceptions(message) unless message.nil?
  end
end
```

Now you just call self method in exception block:

```
AddLog.exceptions 'message_and_stuff'
```

When there is an exception, check `/log/exceptions.log` file.

Comment: Why are you creating a new log file?  Is there a way I can route the exceptions to the existing log?

Comment: @satish I believe it's good practice for rails. If you want to put your message to environment log, just check guid about sending messages for logger class: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger

Comment: Apologies but I do not see anything in the link you sent about why the exceptions thrown in the code I listed aren't showing up in my enviornment specific log file.  What am I missing?

Comment: @satish I'm quoting: "To write in the current log use the `logger.(debug|info|warn|error|fatal)` method". For example just `logger.debug 'message_and_stuff'`

Comment: That would necessitate my catching the exception before using the logger, correct?  So I would have to add code to do that?

Comment: @satish Of course. In either case you should catching the exception.

Comment: I know that seemed liek a fairly obvious question but this is the root of my post.  I don't have to manually catch and log exceptions when they are thrown in the controller or models.  They just magically appear in my log file.  I would like to employ a simlar mechanism here.